# Cannot pick row data when i use onrowselect

Tags: java, primefaces

i am have a primefaces datatable that i want to select row data, the issue is, when click on the row , the action is fired but the row data is not selected.

see codes below

```
<p:dataTable id="itemtab" var="tab"
                                         value="#{ivt.itemModel}"
                                         rows="10"
                                         selectionMode="single"
                                         rowKey="#{tab.id}"
                                         selection="#{ivt.itemtable}"
                                         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  
                                         {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} 
                                         {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} "
                                         paginator="true" style="margin-bottom:20px">
                                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{ivt.onRowSelect}" update=":templateForm:growl" />
                                <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{ivt.onRowUnselect}" update=":templateForm:growl" />
                                <p:column>

                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Vendor ID"/>
                                    </f:facet>

                                    <h:outputText value="#{tab.id}"/>

                                </p:column>

                                <p:column>

                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Item"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{tab.item}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column>

                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Item Type"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{tab.type}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column>

                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Category"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{tab.category}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>

                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Mn. Date"/>
                                    </f:facet>

                                    <h:outputText value="#{tab.startDate}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>

                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Ex. Date"/>
                                    </f:facet>

                                    <h:outputText value="#{tab.enddate}"/>

                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>

                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Amount"/>
                                    </f:facet>

                                    <h:outputText value="#{tab.amount}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column>

                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Bar Code"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{tab.barcode}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>

                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Unit Price"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{tab.unitprice}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>

                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Quantity"/>
                                    </f:facet>


                                    <h:outputText value="#{tab.quantity}"/>
                                </p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>
```

backing bean is this

```
public List<ItemModel> ItemTable() throws Exception {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        DbConnectionX dbConnections = new DbConnectionX();
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {

            con = dbConnections.mySqlDBconnection();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM vendor_item order by id desc";
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            //
            List<ItemModel> lst = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {

                ItemModel ven = new ItemModel();
                ven.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                ven.setVendorId(rs.getString("vendor_id"));
                ven.setItem(rs.getString("item"));
                ven.setAmount(rs.getDouble("amount"));
                ven.setInvoiceId(rs.getString("invoice_id"));
                ven.setQuantity(rs.getDouble("quantity"));
                ven.setCategory(rs.getString("category"));
                ven.setUnitprice(rs.getDouble("unit_price"));
                ven.setCreatedBy(rs.getString("createdby"));
                ven.setDateCreated(rs.getDate("datecreated"));
                ven.setType(rs.getString("type"));
                ven.setStartDate(rs.getString("mndate"));
                ven.setEnddate(rs.getString("exdate"));
                ven.setBarcode(rs.getString("barcode"));

                lst.add(ven);
            }

            return lst;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        } finally {

            if (!(con == null)) {
                con.close();
                con = null;
            }
            if (!(pstmt == null)) {
                pstmt.close();
                pstmt = null;
            }

        }
    }
```

and onselectrowevent is this. i tested, by trying to display at list a column value, but i get just "vendor selected " and nothing else. please assist

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Vendor Selected", ((ItemModel)event.getObject()).getStartDate());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
```

please how do i resolve this? i have been battling with this for days now.
thanks

Comment: try to use `System.out.println(" Vendor" + ((ItemModel)event.getObject()).getStartDate());` to see if the value is null or not , it can be caused by so many things

Comment: yes it is displaying using system.out. but why am i unable to display facesmessages

Comment: try to use this `FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Testing my data   " + ((ItemModel)event.getObject()).getStartDate()));`